# How to findOne or find when array value is blank

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the mongosh terminal to find all the array value is blank

Comment: There is not enough information in that single sentence for us to even begin helping. What is a sample document from the collection? What query are you running? What array are you referring to?  If you update the question with more information then we might be able to make more progress in solving the problem

Comment: I already got the correct query I need.

{$exists: true, $type: 'array', $eq: []} this is what I've used by using this you can find any array with empty value.